# Does EASA (or other regional/national aviation safety authority) have a confidential "close-call" reporting system?

Tags: safety, easa-regulations

Not being a pilot, learned about the [ASRS](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/) from this site. Have any aviation safety authorities in other countries attempted to emulate the ASRS and to what degree was it successful? After all it was introduced in 1976, which is quite a while ago.

I'm mostly interested in European airspace, although examples from other countries/regions are welcome.

Comment: The UK has [CHIRP](https://www.chirp.co.uk/)

Comment: @Simon - nice to know, thanks, are there any cross-country comparative impact assessments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the ASRS, so but I think this is a similar program... It's obviously not Europe, but Australia has the [REPCON](https://www.atsb.gov.au/voluntary/repcon-aviation.aspx) scheme for confidentially reporting all sorts of safety matters. The ATSB do a bit of investigating, seeking a response from the airline/whatever organisation is involved, and then publish the responses to a couple in CASA's Flight Safety Australia magazine.

Comment: Is it a success? Do pilots trust the system?